# grails asynchronous mail plugin and database configuration

Tags: database, email, grails, asynchronous

Did someone has managed successfully to make the asynchronous-mail plugin work with config value coming from the database. In particular config parameter like 'grails.mail.host'.
As a matter of fact the previous parameter has to be defined in the config.groovy.
Yet I'd like to use the embedded H2 database to get its value without having to restart the web app.

I tried to work with the dynamic-db-config-property plugin but it did not work at least with grails 2.3.x . The value is not re-read from the database.

Any suggestion are very welcome,

Thanks

Regards